# How can I get the correct value from base class on this kind of situation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

When I do this, the output is always 0, I know that is an expected behaviour. But I really wonder that is there any way to access the changed value on derived class? Like reflection or something like this...

```
public class BaseClass
{
   protected int a=0;

   public void ChangeA()
   {
       a=5;
   }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
   public void PrintValue()
   {
       Console.Write(a);
   }
}
```

Thank you...

Edit: I noticed that I have to give more detail about this question.

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Program()
    {
         BaseClass baseC = new BaseClass();
         baseC.ChangeA();

         SubClass sub = new SubClass();
         sub.PrintValue();
    }
}
```

In here the print is always 0. I know I can do like that, but I don't want to do this because my base class's ChangeA() method always run in different place(other subclass) ;

```
public class MainClass
{
     public static void Program()
     {
         SubClass sub = new SubClass();
         sub.ChangeA();
         sub.PrintValue();
     }
}
```

or

```
public void PrintValue()
{
    base.ChangeA();
    Console.Write();
}
```

Comment: So, execute `ChangeA()` and access it? I don't see what's the issue in here.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to call sub.ChangeA() method, that is the main reason why "a" equals 0

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine. Check it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7viIiS